# How do I create an in-memory blob with libgit2sharp?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I would like to make a diff between two strings with libgit2sharp. The strings hold file contents loaded elsewhere. The `diff.Compare`-methods only take blobs, and the constructors of the `Blob`class are internal. How do I create blobs without writing the strings to disk?

```
    var oldFileContents = @"
        Line 1
        Line 2
        Line 3
    ";

    var newFileContents = @"
        Line 1
        Line 2 has changed
    ";

    // disk-backed repo
    var path = Repository.Init("C:\\tmp");
    var repo = new Repository(path);

    var oldObjectId = repo.ObjectDatabase.Write<Blob>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oldFileContents));
    var newObjectId = repo.ObjectDatabase.Write<Blob>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newFileContents));
    var oldBlob = repo.Lookup<Blob>(oldObjectId);
    var newBlob = repo.Lookup<Blob>(newObjectId);
    var diff = repo.Diff.Compare(oldBlob, newBlob);  // Works as expected

    // git repo for in-memory operations
    var in_memory_repo = new Repository();

    // This line failes with the LibGit2SharpException "path cannot exist in repository"
    var in_memory_blob = in_memory_repo.ObjectDatabase.Write<Blob>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oldFileContents));
```

After a deep-dive into the codebase, I still cannot see how to create a blob from directly from a string. Any thoughts?

Comment: [This open issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1479) or [this closed issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1692) may be related. The latter mentions in-memory repositories require "special back-ends, which aren't provided." Whatever that means.

Comment: The XMLDoc comments on that constructor you're using say "This is
suitable only for custom, in-memory Git repositories that are
configured with custom object database, reference database and/or
configuration backends." I still don't know what that means, but maybe it's helpful. :-)